# Firstly do Group By then retrieve all rows as per order?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, group-by

I have table where I have id and time.

```
ID  |   Time
1   | 8.35 
1   | 8.40
3   | 8.43
4   | 8.45
1   | 8.50
2   | 8.52
3   | 8.54
4   | 8.55
1   | 8.57
2   | 9.01
3   | 9.05
5   | 9.06
```

Required Result

```
ID  | Time
5   | 9.06
3   | 9.05
3   | 8.54
3   | 8.43
2   | 9.01
2   | 8.52
1   | 8.57
1   | 8.50
1   | 8.40
1   | 8.35
4   | 8.55
4   | 8.45
```

Currently I am doing it by `Select * from table group by ID order by Time DESC` and get

Result One:

```
  ID    | Time

    5   | 9.06

    3   | 9.05

    2   | 9.01

    1   | 8.57

    4   | 8.55
```

then writing second query and storing data in list.

```
foreach value in Result one:
Select * from Table where ID = value
```

Instead of writing a loop, I will like to have only one query.

Basic problem is I want to group IDs and top group should be the item that occured recently. As in example 1 occurs many time but I will consider only the latest time while grouping.

Can I write only one query to get result?

Comment: Show the query you are using

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: `select * from yourtable order by Id, Time`

Comment: do `order by id,time`

Comment: I need to order by time First

Comment: @Ips Not based on the result you are requesting, your order is by ID first (all 1 ids then all 2 ids) then by time (all 1s with the id 1, then all 2s with the id 1 etc) That's the exact difference i see in your two result tables, the first is ordered by time then ID, the second is ordered by ID then time.

Comment: Sorry for that, my problem is i want to group ID's by latest time.

Comment: The new list is still ordered by id then by time `ORDER BY id, time` would return that. You need to give us more info on your query, I don't see any grouping here at all, grouping by ID would return only one row with id 1, one with 2 etc

Comment: Thanks @Andrew I have modified question

Comment: You need "All rows for each id" then you do NOT want GROUP BY. Just run  the query everyone is suggesting `SELECT id, time FROM Table ORDER BY id, time` and you will get the exact results you are requesting.

Comment: If you have an id in your table that doesn't have a time and you want to suppress that one from coming through then add a WHERE clause (totally guessing here since that's not in your example data, but your description suggests it's a possibility): `SELECT id, time FROM table WHERE time IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id, time;`

Comment: Please stop using the word `group` so much, grouping, while in English can mean what you're using it for, it has a very specific meaning in SQL, where your usage is really asking for ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT ID, Time FROM Table ORDER BY ID, Time`

Grouping combines matching rows, so you do not want to group, ordering puts them in order, and that's what you want, you want all the IDs in order then all the times in order within those ids, so you want to order by ID then order by time.

UPDATE due to question edit

This can be done with a join to a sub select

```
SELECT t.ID. t.Time FROM Table t
JOIN (SELECT ID, Max(Time) as Time FROM Table GROUP BY ID) ss
ON t.ID = ss.ID
ORDER BY ss.Time DESC, t.ID DESC, t.Time DESC
```

The sub select (ss) does the first query you have there, and joins it to the main table, letting you order by the highest(max) time for each ID, then by the ID and the Time for the row itself. Note that all the ordering is done on the final query, ordering in the sub select is useless, since the join will reorder it anyways.

Comment: If I do SELECT ID FROM Table ORDER BY ID, Time then it will return first order by id then time for each ID. I am looking for for all timings,  query will select first id with maximum time, then ignore time and display all items for that ID

Comment: @Ips I don't quite follow

Comment: OK Sorry, The solution of the problem in is, Query one: Group by Number order by time. Query 2, Now I will traverse through IDs in previous query to retrieve all items. But I am looking for one query

Comment: @Ips you need to be much clearer with what you want, the query I have written here will give you the data listed under 'I Need:' in the order it is there, if you need something other than that, you need to be specific.

Comment: @Ips its not as hard as you are making it. You have no need to group at all.

Comment: I modified question :)

Comment: Thanks @Andrew  :)

Comment: @Ips Try it out, if it works upvote and accept the answer.